# Double square braces

Tags: verilog, brackets

I'm trying to decipher the following line of code in Verilog:

```
assign ASIC_error_flag   = (StartTransfer & ~Bank_Slct[IO_Config_P2[13:12]]);
```

I suspect it might be a compare between the negated bus "`Bank_Slct`" and bits 13 through 12 of the bus `IO_Config_P2`, but I've never seen a bus inside of a bus like that before. What is this supposed to equate to?

Answer (score 2):

The inner square brackets are used to select a portion of the `IO_Config_P2` signal, and the outer brackets are in turn used to select a portion of the `Bank_Slct` signal.

Let's assume you declared `Bank_Slct` like a memory of 4 bytes:

```
reg [7:0] Bank_Slct [0:3];
```

In this case, you need a 2-bit signal to select one of the 4 bytes (like a memory address).  The expression, `IO_Config_P2[13:12]`, is the 2-bit select signal.

When `IO_Config_P2[13:12]` is equal to `2'b00`, you are selecting byte `Bank_Slct[0]`.

When `IO_Config_P2[13:12]` is equal to `2'b01`, you are selecting byte `Bank_Slct[1]`, etc.

An alternate approach would have been to create a separate signal (`sel`), then use that:

```
wire [1:0] sel = IO_Config_P2[13:12];
assign ASIC_error_flag = (StartTransfer & ~Bank_Slct[sel]);
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.4.4 *Memories*.